# Full headers html email viewer / converter to printable format

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu

I received some reservation confirmations as an attachment - with full headers and html body. Simply opening it in a browser does not give a usable result though. Any software to view such emails, but without a need to register an email account in a desktop client (I tried Geary and stopped at that first step)?

Answer (score 2):

Already solved, Thunderbird[*] lets you register with a dummy account (localhost) then it displays saved messages in a readable format. Make sure you copy the result to your inbox before printing, otherwise you'll get the original html source instead of the readable format.

[*] start it with `$ thunderbird --offline`